# Is it possible to find out unit test code coverage for changesets checked in by select individuals on TFS?

Tags: unit-testing, tfs, code-coverage

I am trying to monitor the unit test code coverage of code checked in by certain individuals in the team. Is this possible through TFS?

Answer (score 2):

A workaround would be to check code coverage of the build before that particular changeset and after the changeset, given that your build definition has code coverage enabled. That way you will be able to see if overall code coverage has improved or not.

Comment: But you can not know how much of the change set have you covered

Answer (score 0):

Seems you want to know if changed code has been covered by tests of a specific changeset.

Unfortunately, there's no out of the box functionality from TFS or Visual Studio to get what you want. The code coverage reports and analysis in Visual Studio and TFS don't take into consideration what code has changed--they only tell you about **code coverage for the entire project or solution.**

There is a [Code Churn and Code Coverage perspectives](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244661.aspx) from the TFS data warehouse. However, it also won't help much. As the code churn perspective **only tracks lines of code that changed**, not including which methods or spelling were changed.

If you really need this feature, you may ask a feature request in [uservoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services), TFS Admin will kindly review it.